# What is the best way to handle Page Objects for different environments?

Tags: selenium, protractor, pageobjects

We have two sits to support, for an example US and Canada. Some pages are exactly the same and some have different options. How I can use page object pattern define pages for this situation and reduce the duplicates?

Let's take the Login page, For US as follows,

```
import { by, element, ElementFinder } from 'protractor';

export class Homepage {

  public startNowButton: ElementFinder;
  public signinLink: ElementFinder;

  constructor() {
    this.startNowButton = element(by.css('button[sso-modal="SignUp"]'));
    this.signinLink = element(by.linkText('Sign in'));
  }
}
```

For Canada, there is an additional checkbox,

```
export class Homepage {

  public startNowButton: ElementFinder;
  public signinLink: ElementFinder;
  public loanPurposeRadio: string;

  constructor() {
    this.startNowButton = element(by.css('button[sso-modal="SignUp"]'));
    this.signinLink = element(by.linkText('Sign in'));
    this.loanPurposeRadio = '[ng-form="loanPurposeField"] label';
  }
}
```

If I want to support both sites then what is the best way to model page objects this kind of situations rather creating two classes? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not JS expert. I did not verify the below code. I am explaining based on how i would achieve that in Java. you can modify accordingly.

I would be creating an abstract class `HomePage` which defines all the common functionalities for all locales. `USHomePage`, `CAHomePage` classes should extend the `HomePage`. Or, You can also use `USHomePage` as Base class `HomePage` and `CAHomePage` will extend this.

Now in the below example, you have all the functionalities of US home page & you have also added specific features of CA.

For ex:

```
 export class CAHomepage extends HomePage {

  public loanPurposeRadio: string;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.loanPurposeRadio = '[ng-form="loanPurposeField"] label';
  }

}
```

Now you could maintain some of kind factory class to return specific instance of HomePage depends on the site you test.

```
var homePageFactory = {
   "US": () => { return new HomePage() },
   "CA": () => { return new CAHomePage() },
   "UK": () => { return new UKHomePage() }
}
```

Based on the locale/country, you can access specific home page. Your tests are not tied to specific site & instead they are very generic. Depends on the site you test, they behave differently.

```
var lang = "US"
var homePage = homepageFactory[lang]();
homePage.login();
homePage.register();
```